# Unable to find Event Receiver template in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, event-receivers, visual-studio-2012

This would probably be right under my nose but I am having a hard time finding it.

I am trying to create an event receiver in Visual Studio 2012. From [this video in YouTube](http://youtu.be/6moBWo93gaI?t=49s) I gather that in Visual Studio 2010 you go to **`File > New > Project`** and inside the new Project dialog box **`SharePoint > 2010`** and select **`Event Receiver`**. So it looks something like this:

[image]

But in Visual Studio 2012 I am unable to find any template for Event Receiver. I tried searching for "event" & "event receiver" in `Search Installed Templates` text box on New Project Dialog but still got no result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot add an event receiver through the "Add new project" dialog. What you do is create an empty sharepoint project first. Then just right click on said sharepoint project, click add new item, go to Office/SharePoint and choose Event Receiver. See my screenshot.

[image: My VS2012]

Comment: Okay... Thanks, it worked. But why did Microsoft take out this option and left the rest of them like Web Part intact?